# Android studio not showing "Screen Record" option for particular Android project

Tags: android, android-studio

I noticed one weird problem on Android Studio version 4.3.2 that is, its not showing "Screen Record" option in "Logcat" section, **this is happening only if I open my "XYZ" project in studio**. Below is my Logcat section's screen shot, please check--

[image]

But the weird thing is, **if I creates new project using same Android Studio, it shows that "Screen Record" option correctly**. So my question is, Do you experts have any idea why I'm facing this issue and How I can resolved it? Also, please let me know if you want me to provide more info on the same. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be missing the whole toolbar. Click the gear icon towards the upper-right of the Logcat window, and choose "Show Toolbar" from there.